# What if the favicon is not named favicon.ico?

Tags: html, w3c, favicon

Are there any restrictions on naming the favorites icon (favicon) file as anything other than **favicon.ico**?

I know for sure that it can be named anything, as long as the favicon tag refers to the correct file name.

For example:

```
<link href="/somefile.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
<link href="/somefile.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

The code above works just fine in displaying the icon.

What I want to know is does this violate any W3C/HTML specifications or this is permitted usage?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? "I know for sure that it can be named anything"

Comment: Yup. What I want to know is if this is against the standards ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon), the preferred method is to actually specify the favicon in the html document rather than relying on favicon.ico in the server root.

Comment: Cool. That settles it then :) Thanks.