# Why does curlExec() have less access than the browser?

Tags: php, file, curl, download

I have an application that downloads favicon files.  Recently I switched from using `file_get_contents` to `curlExec` because it has a higher success rate.

However when I try and download from  www.prisonexp.org , instead of sending the actual file data they send the text `Forbidden.`  Normally, I would see a bunch of binary data converted to ASCII in this field in the test script.

I find this strange because I can just browse to the file in the browser and download it manually.

Is this valid? Or am I missing something?  How are they preventing a download one way but not another.  To see the test script in action go here.

[Test Script](http://arcmarks.com/web/source/class.FaviconFinder.php?domain=prisonexp.org)

As a side, how can I detect when instead of sending binary data, a server sends a message as text?  I could just check for "Forbidden" but I'm not sure if this is a standard response.

**Research / Update**

[Download Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745587/how-to-use-wget-in-php)

Comment: They probably check the `User-Agent` header and blacklist a known set of user agents, such as wget and curl.

Comment: I am able to use `wget http://www.prisonexp.org/favicon.ico` to download the file successfully, so the error may well be in your code. Please post your actual code so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: I've run this script hundreds of time successfully, and I've found this to be the first site/domain that does this.  Strange practice.

Comment: On a side note, not every site uses `favicon.ico` as their Favicon! The favicon can be manually specified on the page, so if you're going for 100% accuracy you may need to parse the actual HTML as well! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691582/what-if-the-favicon-is-not-named-favicon-ico

Comment: Can anyone  take a gander as to why one way has more access than the other, I mean why was that decision made by the architects ?  I'm going to use `wget` and get programmatically any ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that can be done programmatically have to be throttled back or servers could become overwhelmed.

Reading the user-agent is one way this is done.

Wget might have more access as it is commonly used as a command line tool.  Similarly images delivered to your client you will have access to directly.