# favicon doesn't show up unless its name is "favicon.ico" - Local Apache2 Server

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to add a `favicon` to my web page.

It works fine if the icon name is `favicon.ico`. **But what if I don't want it to be named like that ?**

What if I want to add more icons with different sizes. Like a 192x192 for Android Chrome ?

My website isn't live. It's local. It's on Apache2. I have it on a Raspberry Pi and on my Linux PC. Both servers have identical settings/configurations.
It behaves exactly the same on both servers.

All files(html,php,png,ico, etc) are inside one directory: `/var/www/mysite`. I've changed `DocumentRoot` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite` inside `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

I am using Chrome. I cleared the cache. I'm refreshing the page using `SHIFT + F5`, `CTRL + F5` or `F5`; all with similar results.

**Note that it's `index.php` not `index.html`.**
Here is what I've written inside the `head` tag inside `index.php`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    

    <!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#e11422">
    <!-- Windows Phone -->
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#e11422">
    <!-- iOS Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#e11422">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon16x16.ico?v=3" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="favicon-192x192.png">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "master.css">   
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
    $('.text-box').load('events_placeholder.html');
    refresh();
    });
    
    function refresh(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('.text-box').load('events_placeholder.html');
            refresh();
        }, 1000);
    }
</script> -->

<script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button,toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    /* Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it */
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !event.target.matches("#text-input") && !event.target.matches("#button")) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
        }
    }
    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.URR').change(function() {
        var n = $('.URR').val();
        if (n < 1)
            $('.URR').val(1);
        if (n > 10)
            $('.URR').val(10);
    });
    $('.Brightness').change(function() {
        var m = $('.Brightness').val();
        if (m < 2)
            $('.Brightness').val(2);            
        if (m > 99)
            $('.Brightness').val(99);
    });
});
</script>

</head>
```

I've read all that I could find on SO and on Google.
The only thing that came close to answering my questions is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691582/what-if-the-favicon-is-not-named-favicon-ico). But, the question being 8 years old, I really hope that something has changed since then.

## Fix:

The fix I found was to actually include a `favicon.ico`.

Also, thanks to [@Punit Gajjar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127330/punit-gajjar) I was able to find one of the best favicon tools online: [Real Favicon Generator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/).

I recommend it to everyone who's trying to make a favicon.
After using the **Favicon Generator** I've added all the files generated (png, ico) to where `index.php` is located and also the following code inside the `head` tag:

```
    <!-- iOS App Icon-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png?v=476mA4zprB">
    <!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=476mA4zprB">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=476mA4zprB">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest?v=476mA4zprB">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=476mA4zprB" color="#e11422">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=476mA4zprB">
    <!-- Tab Color iOS Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="#e11422">
    <meta name="application-name" content="#e11422">
    <!-- Tile Color Microsoft Windows Shortcut -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#b91d47">
    <!-- Tab Color Android Chrome -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#e11422">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the .`png` file you must use the `type="image/png"` attributes, like below.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

Make sure that the path you have given is the absolute.

Comment: `<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="favicon-192x192.png">` had `type="image/png"`. I forgot to add it back. I just did and nothing changed.
Also, what about this: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon16x16.ico?v=3" type="image/x-icon">` ? Why isn't this working ?
Why should my path be absolute ? All the files are in the same directory as the index.php. What more an I do ?

Comment: @bleah1 ,check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121725/favicon-ico-or-png-correct-tags